# Agile Project Management

Tags: project-management, agile

If one does use Scrum for the Software development portion of a project, does one still use PMBOK or some other project management methodology for the "other" tasks on a project e.g. the business, marketing, training tasks.  What is the project management of non software development tasks referred to i.e. traditional project management?

Comment: I think this question would be good for [Programmers.SE], if it's not too old to migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have expanded scrum to other departments in the company, modeling, texture and animation artist. We had to adapt the method a little, but it does work nicely. We had problems that were solved by using agile methodology. Some smaller departments (audio, special effects) were already working fine so we didn't tried to fix what wasn't broken. Agile would have added an unnecessary overhead for them.

It is not necessary for all departments in a company to use the same methodology, the best is to be adapted for everyones' needs. But scrum can be the solution for people other than programmers, but may need a bit of adaptation. Daily stand-up, sprints, backlog, those can be a good thing for many types of jobs.

Comment: How have you implemented SCRUM in other departments, do you have a list of tasks that people volunteer for or do you assign tasks?

Answer (score 2):

A project is defined in the PMBOK as being something of fixed scope, duration and budget. Failure of the project is defined as breaking outside one of the three sides of this "iron triangle". Scrum is a set of principles, and a few concrete practices, for dealing with all sorts of knowledge work, based on Agile values, and is specifically designed for development efforts that may not be projects, or may have flexible scope, duration or budget.

You are right that Scrum only deals with a few aspects of the software development process, such as planning. It only defines a few roles, meetings and artifacts, this is to keep it as flexible as possible. Scrum can, and should, address parts of the value stream outside of the software development itself. However, as you mentioned, it does not deal with lots of things, such as software engineering practices, and analysing the business case.

Often the standard Scrum solution is to "let the team decide" on matters that are not directly specified by Scrum. Often the guidelines for dealing with such matters come from other cultures and value or principle-systems within the Agile world, such as XP, or lean software development. Other cultures providing useful stuff for Scrum teams include Real Options, the Incremental Funding Method, Evo.

Some of the PMBOK stuff can be useful to a "project manager" or PO on a Scrum team, however one has to be cautious as the PMBOK stuff implies a rather different value-system than that which Scrum is based on. It is usually best to look for solutions within the Agile culture. Some of the PMBOK stuff still applies in an agile context though.

If you look for mailing lists related to "agile project management" you will find many thriving communities discussing such topics.

Answer (score 2):

Agile development and PMBOK should not be mixed. IF you do, you're likely to end up with [Scrummerfall](http://www.agileprogrammer.com/dotnetguy/archive/2006/07/08/16855.aspx). I've seen this happen with traditional project managers who convert to agile. They just don't get it and seem to fall back to old patterns.

However, in my opinion SCRUM doesn't cover all you need for project management. It sort of lacks an overall strategy to rule by. One possibility is combining SCRUM with [EVO project/value management](http://www.result-planning.com/) or other value management methods. It will however require a different type of legal contract with the customer. Projects are then more like a continuous process  that is time boxed, restrained by a budget or ends when the customer feels he gains less than his investment (using business cases and goal measures). An added benefit is that the customer will see you more as a long term partner than a short term supplier.

Comment: I've tried reading up on EVO project/value management but find the material very complicated and verbose. Have you used this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If your software development effort is just one facet of a larger project--for example, rolling out a new financial product--then sure, you will have to employ some kind of project management methodology to orchestrate all of the work involved. Fitting a Scrum-based software development effort into a project managed according to PMBOK principles can be challenging, however, since PMBOK prescribes a linear, phased approach to project execution whereas Scrum, like other Agile methodologies, promotes incremental improvement through iteration. That's not to say that the two can't coexist. Like everything else, it comes down to implementation. Just remember to be pragmatic and adapt the methodologies to your needs, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

Scrum is NOT a software development method but a project management method.

Besides Scrum is often introduced with [Lego](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/lego_city_game/), or other artefacts (search for "59 minutes Scrum"). 
Therefore it can be used to handle all of the tasks of a project, whatever their natures.

Answer (score -1):

While learning about these techniques is great, can I suggest your main focus is actually on running the project and getting stuff done?

EDIT: that's a serious point by the way, not a throwaway quip.